# Making two time-series with different sampling rates comparable

Tags: python, statistics

I have 2 sets of data, both time series that are Variable (same in both cases) vs. Time and I have imported and plotted them using pandas and matplotlib.

```
from os import chdir
chdir('C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Folder')

# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read in csv file
file_df = pd.read_csv('C://Users//me//Documents//Folder//file.csv')

# define csv columns and assign values
VarA = file_df.loc[:, 'VarA'].values
TimeA = file_df.loc[:, 'TimeA'].values
VarB = file_df.loc[:, 'VarB'].values
TimeB = file_df.loc[:, 'TimeB'].values


# plot data selection and aesthetics
plt.plot(TimeA, VarA)
plt.plot(TimeB, VarB)

# plot labels
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Variable')

#plot and add legend based on plot labels
plt.legend()
```

In both cases, the variable is sampled between 0 minutes and 320 minutes. However, one data set has 775 samples (taken at random intervals across the 320 minutes) and the other data set has 1732 samples (again, taken at random intervals across the 320 minutes).

Essentially what I want to do is make two new datasets, based on the old ones, where I have the variable vs time between 0 and 320 minutes but both with the same amount of data points for variable A taken at the same time steps (e.g. variable at every minute for 320 samples).

I'm guessing some interpolation is required? I genuinely don't know where to start. I have both datasets in the same .csv and I need them to be the same sample size so that I can run the following calculation. At the moment it doesn't run because 'VarA' and 'VarB' have different amounts of data.

```
x_values = VarB
y_values = VarA

correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(x_values, y_values)
correlation_xy = correlation_matrix[0,1]
r_squared = correlation_xy**2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) might be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to solve this. What is the problem that you're trying to solve by calculating the correlation between two variables over time?

One option is to calculate some kind of weighted moving average over time, and then do the correlation that way. The simplest way to do this is an exponentially weighted moving average, like the [loess](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/loess) function. There are more sophisticated methods too.

Here's some example code, where I took a cosine function and the same function with random noise added. To do a loess fit, use the loess() function, and to get access to the fitted values you want the "fitted" variable of value returned by lowess.

```
x = seq(from = 1, to = 100)
y1 = cos(x / 10)
y2 = cos(x / 10) + rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 0.25)

smooth_y2 = loess(y2 ~ x)
plot(x, y1, type = 'l')
lines(x, smooth_y2$fitted, type = 'l', col = 'red')
print(cor(y1, smooth_y2$fitted))
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the reply.

I'm trying to calculate the R squared value to quantitatively compare the two datasets. I'm using one dataset as 'the model' and the other as a timeseries against which I use the model to calculate the R squared.

As for the code you left, I'm sorry but I am a complete noobie, I know lnext to nothing about python and programing theory as a whole. Could you try to explain it in a way I might understand a bit more?